# Not receiving multi line response ELM 327

Tags: obd-ii, hyundai, diagnostics, dtc, elm-327

I am sending the following commands to my Hyundai i20 2012 model (OBDLink SX Bluetooth device):

```
AT Z
AT H1
AT L1
AT S1
AT AL
AT SP6
AT SH 7D1
18 00 FF 00
```

The response I am getting is 7D9 10 0B 58 03 51 02 80 52.

```
7D9 - response for header 7D1
10 - line no.
0B - 0B(in hex) bytes of data valid (0B = 11 in decimal)
```

So I should get multiple  lines of data and 3 fault codes. But I am receiving only this 1st line of data always. How do I get the remaining lines? Am I missing any AT command for the ELM 327?

I tried AT CM 000, AT CF 000, AT ST FF but not of much use. I always keep getting the 1st line of data only.

Comment: I see you're using AL, have you tried AR?  I'm not sure what it does, but "automatic receive" sounds like something worth investigating.

Comment: @JPhi1618 No AT AR doesn't work too

Answer (score 1):

you need to send 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 to get the remaining response frames